# Traversing Through GridView Data

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable

I need to loop through a gridview to then compare it to my database.

this is what i have now:

```
   Dim rows As Integer = gwResults.Rows.Count()
    For Each row As GridViewRow In gwResults.Rows
        'move through rows and check data in each row against the dataset
        cSource.GetDetails(Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells(1).Text))
    Next
```

is it possible to get gridview values in each column by calling them by a name, instead of index? so maybe have something like cells("userID") instead of cells(5)
i have many columns, and indexes could get really confusing.

Comment: You could for example use a typed dataset. Then every column has its own property witht he appropriate datatype.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable paging in your GridView your approach wouldn't work at all, because then iterating Rows would only traverse the rows of the current PageIndex(by default 10 Rows).

You should use the DataSource of your GridView as source for your iteration. 
If you would provide more informations on what you're trying to do, we could assist you.

Comment: i am loading data from excel into a gridview, and then i want to compare the values to my SQL tables to see if they match.

Comment: @xrum: To be honest, i would do that on database side. For example importing all rows into a temp-Table, then compare them via SQL(either per View in DB, per stored-procedure or from the application) and then do what you want with the result. Of course you could that that in the code too. Load your excel values via OleDbDataReader into a (typed) DataTable. You can use this as datasource for the grid as well as to compare the values with the DB.